# (JQuery) Output is undefined when getting a value from a dynamically created input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, firebase-realtime-database

I am making an inventory database using JS and JQuery to firebase realtime database. The only problem I have now is when I input my values and run the function, it reads as undefined in the console log so it doesn't add data to the database and runs an error because it's undefined.

> Uncaught Error: set failed: value argument contains undefined in property 'Inventory.undefined.Quantity'

**This is the code to add inputs to the table:**

```
$(".add-new").click(function(){
  $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
  var index = $("table tbody tr:last-child").index();
  var row = '<tr>' +
      '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name"></td>' +
      '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="unit" id="unit"></td>' +
      '<td>' + actions + '</td>' +
  '</tr>';
  $("table").append(row);       
  $("table tbody tr").eq(index + 1).find(".add, .edit").toggle();
});
```

**This is the code making the input into a variable:**

```
$(document).on("click", ".add", function(){
            var empty = false;
            var input = $(this).parents("tr").find('input[type="text"]');
            input.each(function(){
                if(!$(this).val()){
                    $(this).addClass("error");
                    empty = true;
                } else{
                    $(this).removeClass("error");
                }
            });
            $(this).parents("tr").find(".error").first().focus();
            if(!empty){
                input.each(function(){
                    $(this).parent("td").html($(this).val());
                });         
                $(this).parents("tr").find(".add, .edit").toggle();
                $(".add-new").removeAttr("disabled");
                let name = $(this).parents("tr").find("input[name=name]").val();
                let unit = $(this).parents("tr").find("input[name=unit]").val();
                console.log(name,unit);
                set(ref(db, 'Inventory/' + name), {
                    Quantity: unit
                });
            }   
                
        });
```

**This is the output for the console log:**

> undefined undefined

Comment: Off topic:  if you use `var tr = $(row).appendTo("table")` then `tr` will contain a jquery object for your newly inserted tr and you can do `tr.find(".add,.edit"...` instead of `.eq(index+1)` etc.

Comment: Without seeing the full code (eg for `input`) - it *looks like* you're removing your inputs before you get their values.  `input.each(function(){ $(this).parent("td").html($(this).val());` finds every input and, if it's in a `td` removes that input by rewriting the `td's html.  So it's very likely that your `input[name=name]` no longer exists after this code.  Try moving that .each to the end of the `if(!empty)`